# MouseEnter and MouseLeave

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a user control in WPF.  I have a button control within the control.  I want the control to fade in and out when the mouse enters and leaves the control.  The problem is when the mouse enters the button and leaves the control, it fades.  Below is the code.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfPresentationEditor.PresentationWindowControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="68" d:DesignWidth="793">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="onMouseEnter">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="onMouseLeave">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="onMouseEnter_BeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource onMouseEnter}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="onMouseLeave_BeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource onMouseLeave}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource onMouseLeave}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Opacity=".5">
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"></Canvas>
    <Button Click="btnClose_Click" Height="44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="btnClose" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="44" Margin="12,12,0,12">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="images/exit.png" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I think you'll either need to use mouse capturing (via code-behind) or  drop the inner button and create and manage the button yourself.  Because the button is going to stop the "bubbling" of the mouse events as it uses those events itself.  I'm not 100% sure on this (hence my comment) so I'm curious if anyone else has alternate solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to make this work as desired.

I changed the RoutedEvent to UserControl.MouseEnter rather than Mouse.MouseEnter.

Then I created my own user control and created an Image button like this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton.aspx.

So my altered code now looks like this....

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfPresentationEditor.PresentationWindowControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="68" d:DesignWidth="793" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfPresentationEditor">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="exitImage" ImageSource="images/exit.png"/>
        <!--These are the story boards for the control-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="onMouseEnter">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="onMouseLeave">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                    <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="onMouseEnter_BeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource onMouseEnter}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="onMouseLeave_BeginStoryBoard" Storyboard="{StaticResource onMouseLeave}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource onMouseLeave}" />
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black">
    <my:ImageButtonControl ButtonBase.Click="btnClose_Click" x:Name="imageButtonControl1" Width="44" Image="images/exit.png" Height="44"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make 2 controls, one containing everything but your button and another one with just the button.
Then put them both in a grid so they will stack upon each other, and voila.